# How do I access the text in a text box from a button click event handler

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to write this simple winform menu and I need to add the contents of the NBox text box to a string so I can display it when a button is pressed, however I keep getting the error that NBox does not exist in the current context. So, how would i got about making the contents of the text box available at the press of a button?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
//namespace game{
class MainM : Form{

public MainM(){

    Text = "Adventures Main Menu";
    Size = new Size(400,400);

    //NameBox
    TextBox NBox = new TextBox();
    NBox.Location = new Point(145, 100);
    NBox.Size = new Size(200, 30);

    //Title Label

    Label title = new Label();
    title.Text = "ADVENTURE THE GAME";
    title.Location = new Point(145, 30);
    title.Size =  new Size(200,60);
    title.Font = new Font(defaultFont.FontFamily, defaultFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold);

    //The main menu Buttons and all that jazz
    Button credits = new Button();
    Button start = new Button();

    //Credits Button
    credits.Text = "Credits";
    credits.Size = new Size(75,20);
    credits.Location = new Point(145,275);
    credits.Click += new EventHandler(this.credits_button_click);

    //Start Button
    start.Text = "Start";
    start.Size = new Size(75,20);
    start.Location = new Point(145,200);
    start.Click += new EventHandler(this.start_button_click);


    //Control addition
    this.Controls.Add(title);
    this.Controls.Add(credits);
    this.Controls.Add(start);
    this.Controls.Add(NBox);
}

  public void test(){
            //The Main Window
  }

  private void credits_button_click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    MessageBox.Show("Created by: Me");
  }

 private void start_button_click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    this.Hide();
    string name = NBox.Text;
    MessageBox.Show(name);

    //Process.Start("TextGame.exe");
 }

  public static void Main(){
    Application.Run(new MainM());
  }

} 
//}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to name the control, that name will be its key in container's Controls collection :

```
//NameBox
TextBox NBox = new TextBox();
NBox.Location = new Point(145, 100);
NBox.Size = new Size(200, 30);
NBox.Name = "NBox"; //Naming the control
```

Then you will be able to retrieve it from the container:

```
private void start_button_click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    this.Hide();
    TextBox NBox= (TextBox)Controls.Find("NBox", true)[0];//Retrieve controls by name        
    string name = NBox.Text;
    MessageBox.Show(name);
    //Process.Start("TextGame.exe");
}
```

Comment: While this is nice and this works, do not do this ! This is not correct way to do things.

Comment: @IvanP it depends from program requirements,  some times it is not posible to have a variable reference to each control. In such cases this is one way to go. If I need a variable reference I prefer to add the control at design time dont you agree?

Comment: I certainly disagree. This approach should never be used.

Answer (score 0):

You declared NBox in consturctor and it is visible only inside constructor. You need to move it outside of constructor.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
//namespace game{
class MainM : Form{
    TextBox NBox;

    public MainM(){

    Text = "Adventures Main Menu";
    Size = new Size(400,400);

    //NameBox
    NBox = new TextBox();
    ...
```

Comment: I dont see the point to having a variable level TextBox here, clearly he is dinamically creating controls...